# Form Validation not working with tel, email and select

Tags: html, forms, validation

I use Dreamweaver to write my html code, but now have run into a problem.

I have created an enquiry form which contains several different fields, but when I try to validate the form using Window | Behavior | Validate Form, it only shows my "firstname", "lastname", "Datepicker1", "Datepicker2" as well as the "Comments" field.

I want to make sure that the telephone, email and select fields are required and will be filled by a number and an email address. It worked fine when I made the contact form, but for some reason it does not in the enquiry.

My code is as follows:

```
<form action="../../enquiryform.php" method="post" id="enquiry">
        <h1>ENQUIRE ABOUT<br><span style="color:#816122">VILLA 2610</span></h1>
        <input type="hidden" name="villaid" id="villaid" value="2610">
        <br>
        Arrival Date<br>
        <input type="text" name="arrivaldate" id="Datepicker1">
        <br>Departure Date<br>
        <input type="text" name="departuredate" id="Datepicker2"><br>
        First Name
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
        Last Name
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
        Telephone
        <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel"><br>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
        <div class="leftcolumn">Adults<br>
        <select name="adults" id="adults">
        <option value=""> </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10+">10+</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn">Children<br>
        <select name="children" id="children">
          <option value=""> </option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10+">10+</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        Comments (optional)<br>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" wrap="soft" style="width:150px; height:100px;"></textarea><br>
        <p class="antispam">Leave this empty: <input name="url" type="text" id="url" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" style="background-color:#aa802c; color:#FFFFFF; border-radius:5px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;"><br><br>
```

I have added the following inside the starting form bracket:

```
onSubmit="MM_validateForm('firstname','','R','lastname','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"
```

But what should I use for a telephone number, email address as well as the 2 select options that I have?

My suggestion is

```
onSubmit="MM_validateForm('firstname','','R','lastname','','R','tel','','RisNum','email','','RisEmail',);return document.MM_returnValue"
```

But how do I add that I require for my viewers to select children and adults options?
And are my thoughts above correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [require attribute on input tag like this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required)

```
Telephone
<input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" required>
```

Comment: But then will it take that is has to be in shape of a number?

Same if I use
'<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>'

will that then require the input to be in the shape of an email?